# How many free cars are there, and where do I get them?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

So far over several playthroughs I have come across a handful of a couple of free vehicles - a Rayburn that I found in the caves after dealing with a Raffen Shiv boss, a Porsche 911 that used to belong to a rockerboy and a Delamain taxi.

Are there any more free cars in Cyberpunk 2077, and if so where do I find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of several cars besides the ones you mention:

- **V's Car** - It's crappy, but it's yours once Delamain repairs it.
- **Jackie's Arch** - After the prologue, you receive this.
- **Brennan Apollo "Scorpion"** - Received after doing the first of Panam's quests.
- **ARCH Nazaré "Itsumade"** - Reward for finding and completing the unmarked "The Highwayman" Quest.
- **Thorton Mackinaw "Beast"** - Reward for completing the last race in Claire's racing quest chain.
- **Quadra Type-66 "Cthulhu"** - Potential reward for completing the last race in Claire's racing quest chain.
- **Villefort Alvarado "Vato"** - You can get this from the "Beat on the Brat: The Glen" quest, in lieu (or in addition to) the cash reward from winning.
- **Quadra Turbo-R V-Tech** - Another quest reward, this time for stealing back a car as part of a Gig: "Life's Work".

Answer (score 5):

You can get a free **Mizutani Shion “Coyote”** if, during the quest **With a Little Help From My Friends**, you inform Saul about Panam’s plans, rather than helping her and the crew out.

This will lock you out of Panam’s remaining quests however.

There is also a **Colby CX 410 Butte** just sitting, waiting to be claimed, at an old abandoned film set in the Badlands, not far from the **Rocky Ridge** fast travel point.

Finally, players who started with the Nomad life path will be able to reclaim their **Thorton Galena** from the badlands junkyards. You’ll receive a message in game starting a quest to go pick it up, and either pay 100 Eddie’s, or simply threaten violence, to reclaim your ride.

Answer (score 2):

It's perhaps worth pointing out that you can also get free cars at almost any point by carjacking a car you see nearby, whether it's currently being occupied by someone or not. Some cars are locked, but many allow you to oust the driver or simply get in the driver's seat and use the car (including police or MaxTac vehicles) without raising your "wanted" level. If the car has a driver in it, you may need a certain strength level (e.g. 8) to pull the driver out. The necessary level will be shown next to the dialogue option, just like encountering a door you can force open.

Such cars aren't "owned" by you and can't be called to you after taking one and then getting out of it, and you can't use them to access your Stash, but they *are* technically free cars.

Comment: This should mention that some cars will have a strength requirement in order to force the driver out to steal the car.

Comment: @Kadima Good point, I had forgotten about that since it's so low.